# Get User Subsite / Multisite URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I am looking at a way to echo the url of the subsite of the user but it just seems to echo both the Network and Subsite of the account with the following function, what can I improve? Thanks!

```html
// Add Shortcode
function blog_url_shortcode() {
 if(is_user_logged_in()) {
  global $current_user;
  $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->id );
  if($blogs) {
   foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
    echo '<li><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'">' .  $blog->blogname . '</a></li>';
   }
  }
 }
}
add_shortcode( 'blog_url', 'blog_url_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Tell me exactly which sites you want to echo, and I will answer. Do you want the current subsite, or all the sites where the current user has any role, or all sites where the current user has an administrator role?

Comment: Hi Nikolay, there is only one subsite for each user, but it seems to still echo the parent site and the subsite the user created. 
I would like to echo the subsite the user created.
Thanks.

Comment: If your code is showing the main network site (I assume this is what you mean by parent site), this means that the user has a role in it (even if it is only subscriber). You are saying that you want sites that the user created. I will answer with a code that shows the sites where the current user is an administrator. That should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will list the sites in which the current user has an administrator role.

Also by the way, there is a new way to get the current user ID, and to get the site URL, that you should use. Your code produced a PHP notice because of the way you get the current user ID.

```
function blog_url_shortcode() {
    if( is_user_logged_in()) {
        $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user_id );
        foreach ( $blogs as $blog_id => $blog ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $current_user_id, '', $blog_id );
            if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $blog->siteurl ) . '">' .  esc_html( $blog->blogname ) . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'blog_url', 'blog_url_shortcode' );
```